# Scala + Play + Slick + freeslick + MS SQL Server: SQLServerException: Cannot update identity column 'ID'

Tags: scala, playframework, slick-3.0

This is a really simple use case. Read an entity out and update it. But slick apparently doesn't know not to update an identity column. Surely I'm doing something wrong.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. Assume data exists in the table, I've just omitted the create steps.

```
case class Foo(id:Option[Long], bar:String)

class FooTable(tag:Tag) extends Table [Foo](tag, Some("schema"), "Foo") {
    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def bar = column[String]("bar")

    def * = ( id, bar) <> ((Foo.apply _).tupled, Foo.unapply)
}

class FooDAO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) {
    val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
    val db = dbconfig.db
    val Foos = TableQuery[FooTable]

    def get(id:Long): Future[Option[Foo] = {
        db.run(Foos.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
    }

    def update(foo:Foo): Future[Int] = {
        db.run(Foos.filter(_.id === foo.id).update(foo))
    }
}

...
class FooController @Inject(fooDao:FooDAO)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
    ...
    private def doFooUpdate(id:Long, newBar:String): Unit = {

        fooDao.get(id).map { fooOption => 
            // assume it exists and the .get() doesn't throw exception
            fooDao.update(fooOption.get().copy(bar=newBar)) // kaboom
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

> Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot update identity column 'id'.

Debug logging shows the SQL statement:

> [debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: update "schema"."Foo" set "id" = ?, "bar" = ? where "schema"."Foo"."id" = 1234

From build.sbt:

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.2",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.2",
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.0",
      "org.suecarter" %% "freeslick" % "3.1.1.2",
      ...
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `update` method to this

```
def update(foo:Foo): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(Foos.filter(_.id === foo.id).map(_.bar).update(foo.bar))
}
```

The problem with the earlier version is you are trying to update the primary auto inc id along with bar which is not allowed as you see from the error message.

Comment: So if I have a wide table I will need to enumerate each column this way in the update?